# The process cannot access the file 'C:\file.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, logging, text-files, streamwriter

I am trying to log each method on my program, I have the application deployed on IIS Server and the user just called me and said the email functionality is not working so I need to basically run the application but log each step into a txt file.

I am declaring the below as a global value:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\file.txt");
```

Then I use it like below in my code:

```
Method 1
{
  if (file1.HasFile)
 {
 writer.WriteLine("Has File");
}
}
```

Method 2

```
private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
 writer.WriteLine("Insert Started" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

So in my case method one runs fine and it writes Has File but when it goes into the second method I get the file is already open which is correct how can I work around this?

Thanks

Global Value - declared at top

```
namespace WorkOrderManagement
{
    public partial class CreateWorkOrder : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        bool successfull;
        string path;
        string name;
        string content;
        string datas;
        string ext;
        bool affectedrows;
        string seasonalsupervisor;
        private string sLogFormat;
        private string sErrorTime;

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\file.txt");
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "global value"? You mean a `static` member?  You realize that IIS is multi-threaded, and static members are shared by ALL requests, right?

Comment: It's a little confusing the code you show but it seems you need to release the writer and you're not doing it.

Comment: "how can I work around this?" Don;t use a "global" stream.  Open the file, write to it, close it (preferably by using a `using` block).

Comment: @DStanley I declared it at the top

Comment: Let me understand this: the file file.txt is located in the C:\ root drive of the PC where the IIS server runs?

Comment: @Steve yea it will be located on the C:\ of the IIS Server. I am first testing out the logging functionality on my local machine that is when it is throwing out the error.

Comment: Based on your code I would wager you are never closing the stream. So unless the process dies somehow the file will never be released.

Comment: That location is highly not recommended. There are permissions that prevent a non administrator to write there, and what would happen if you deploy your site where you don't have administrative permissions to read the root of the server? Besides your problems are caused by the ASP.NET Page life cycle. When you call the second method that is a different instance of the page than the one that opened the file in the first method. Follow the advice by @DStanley or simply use the File.AppendLine method

Comment: Why declare the `StreamWriter` at the class level? You should write a method to write the log with the writer in a `using`, to ensure it's disposed when you're done with it. You can even synchronize access to it with a `lock` since there could be multiple concurrent requests as it's IIS.

Comment: Logging in a multi-threaded environment like IIS presents a number of challenges. You can choose to re-invent the wheel, or you can use a mature, well-known, and stable tool like log4net. See http://www.dotnetlogging.com/ for a list of choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suggest you to discard the idea to have a global variable to represent a stream and then try to use it in different methods. This is simple in a desktop application, but a lot more complex in an ASP.NET application.

There are simple alternatives that could atomically write your log text and leave the file unlocked.

For example you could have a method like this

```
public static class Log
{
    public static string _file = "log.txt";
    public static object _locked = new object();

    public static void AppendToLog(string text)
    {
         lock(_locked)
         {
             string path = Server.MapPath("~/APP_DATA");
             File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(path, _file), text + Environment.NewLine);
         } 
    }
}
```

Now you can call the log write with

```
Log.AppendToLog("My message");
```

I want to underline two important things here. First I don't write in the root drive of the server. This is a bad practice and always a source of problems when you deploy your ASP.NET application in a server where you have not permissions to use anything outside your site root. Thus the ASP.NET system defines a particular folder called APP_DATA under your site root where your application should have read/write permissions.
Second point to notice is the use of the lock keyword. This is necessary in an environment like ASP.NET where two users could reach a point of the code where you need to write to the common log file. As MSDN explains it

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical
>   section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If
>   another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block,
>   until the object is released.

Comment: Thank You very much your an coding angel :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this to close the file stream

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\file.txt"))
{
   //your code here
}
//this automatically closes the stream, and it is more recommended.
```

Comment: I cant do the above because I have an another method within the method that does the insert into database so before the streamwriter closes it goes into the other method and says txt file is used by another process.

Comment: This doesn't solve the fundamental problem, which is that two threads are trying to access the same file concurrently. If both try to write at the same time, the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Close the stream after writing the file

```
Method 1
{
  if (file1.HasFile)
 {
 writer.WriteLine("Has File");
 writer.Close();
 }
}
```

Comment: you method gives me this error  "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter."

Comment: Because StreamWriter.Close() needs to reopen after closing if you want to use it again. Then you should do: `writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\file.txt");` at the beginning of your second method.

Comment: This doesn't solve the fundamental problem. If two threads try to open and write to the file, he'll experience the same problem. There has to be some kind of explicit synchronization.